# Chromecast DRM example

Tags: javascript, android, chromecast

I am referring to this example given by Google (sender.js file in particular) (https://github.com/googlecast/CastMediaPlayerStreamingDRM/blob/master/sender.js). I am trying to play the http: //storage.googleapis.com/wvmedia/cenc/tears.mpd file which is DRM and I am passing in the license URL http:// widevine-proxy.appspot.com/proxy as defined in the sender.js file in the example.

My sender is Android (I am using the CastCompanionLibrary). This is how I am sending it in Android:

```
mCastManager.sendDataMessage("http://playready.directtaps.net/pr/svc/rightsmanager.asmx");
mCastManager.startCastControllerActivity(LocalPlayerActivity.this, media, 0, true);
```

This is how I am receiving the license URL in the my custom receiver:

```
messageBus = castReceiverManager.getCastMessageBus(--NAME SPACE--);

messageBus.onMessage = function(event) {

        console.log(event['data']);
        licenseURL = event['data'];
        console.log(licenseURL);

    }
```

So far I have debugged and licenseURL is set to the license URL sent by the Android sender. It is receiving the licenseURL properly in the receiver. Then in my onLoad method I do the following.

```
 mediaManager.onLoad = function(event) {

        if(mediaPlayer !== null) {
            mediaPlayer.unload(); // Ensure unload before loading again
        }

        if (event.data['media'] && event.data['media']['contentId']) {
            var url = event.data['media']['contentId'];

            mediaHost = new cast.player.api.Host({
                'mediaElement': mediaElement,
                'url': url
            });

            mediaHost.onError = function (errorCode) {
                console.error('### HOST ERROR - Fatal Error: code = ' + errorCode);

                if (mediaPlayer !== null) {
                    mediaPlayer.unload();
                }
            }

            if(licenseURL){

                console.log("##License URL is not null");
                mediaHost.licenseURL = licenseURL;
            }
            var initialTimeIndexSeconds = event.data['media']['currentTime'] || 0;

            var protocol = null;

            var parser = document.createElement('a');
            parser.href = url;

            var ext = ext = parser.pathname.split('.').pop();
            if (ext === 'm3u8') {
                protocol =  cast.player.api.CreateHlsStreamingProtocol(mediaHost);
            } else if (ext === 'mpd') {
                protocol = cast.player.api.CreateDashStreamingProtocol(mediaHost);
            } else if (ext === 'ism/') {
                protocol = cast.player.api.CreateSmoothStreamingProtocol(mediaHost);
            }
            console.log('### Media Protocol Identified as ' + ext);


            if (protocol === null) {

                mediaManager['onLoadOrig'](event); // Call on the original callback
            } else {

                mediaPlayer = new cast.player.api.Player(mediaHost);
                mediaPlayer.load(protocol, initialTimeIndexSeconds);
            }
        }
    }
```

But when I do this I am getting the error:

```
XMLHttpRequest cannot load http://storage.googleapis.com/wvmedia/cenc/tears.mpd. No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource. Origin 'https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com' is therefore not allowed access.
### HOST ERROR - Fatal Error: code = 3
```

I am hosting the receiver temporarily on dropbox public folder. Any ideas as to what I am doing wrong?

Answer (score 0):

Your server that is hosting your media is not sending CORS headers which is required. You need to add those, see this [document](https://developers.google.com/cast/docs/player), section Using Cross-Origin Resource Sharing (CORS).

Comment: The media is an example given in that github repository by Google. I don't have access to it? How are we supposed to run that example without the CORS headers?

Comment: I am asuuming storage.googleapis.com is hosting the media in the example I mentioned. (I wanted this particular one because I need media and a license URL to test DRM). Anyway I can add CORS headers to this?

Comment: Google's Cloud Storage allows you to add CORS headers to your bucket easily (as long as you have permissions to do so on the associated project). Here is the instructions: https://developers.google.com/storage/docs/cross-origin

Comment: Thanks for that link. As I mentioned in the original post, I am using the CastMediaPlayerStreamingDRM example given. And I wanted to test with th 3rd mpd file in the sender.js. Because of the CORS issue, I am sending the video link as "http://www.corsproxy.com/storage.googleapis.com/wvmedia/cenc/tears.mpd" and not setting any credentials in the onLoad method of the receiver but still setting the licenseURL (given in the CastMediaPlayerStreamingDRM example).

Comment: It seems to work (although stream crashes in like 5-10 secs). But the stream seems to work (for 5-10 secs) with or without setting the licenseURL. Shouldn't it not stream for those 5-10 secs if I dont set the licenseURL? How are we supposed to use the CastMediaPlayerStreamingDRM example?

Comment: Instructions are on the same page as part of the README.md file for that project

Comment: I followed the instructions in it and resolved the CORS problem. But the license URL issue seems to be still there. The video plays with or without me setting the licenseURL like mediaHost.licenseURL = licenseURL

Comment: I just wanted to try the CastMediaPlayerStreamingDRM example as is and am getting the CORS error on the Tears of Steel. The sample is hosted by Google so I don't think I can change the permissions there. I have looked in the README.md, but don't see anything explaining how to resolve this. Could you please be more specific on how you resolved this?